# How to get first day of each month in datetimeindex, when month doesn't starts with 01?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a DataFrame with DateTimeIndex, for 10 years, day by day. I need to extract rows which corresponds to first day of each month. However not all months starts with 01, some starts with 02, 03, 04 etc.

```
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
...
2020-01-31
2020-02-03
...
2020-02-29
2020-03-02
```

Expected df must be:

```
2020-01-02
2020-02-03
2020-03-02
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) for months periods, then test duplicates by [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask for first days of months:

```
#if necessary
df = df.sort_index()

print (df)
            A
date         
2020-01-02  4
2020-01-03  9
2020-01-31  2
2020-02-03  7
2020-02-29  3
2020-03-02  1

df1 = df[~df.index.to_period('m').duplicated()]
print (df1)
            A
date         
2020-01-02  4
2020-02-03  7
2020-03-02  1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.index.to_period('m'))
PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-01', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03'], 
            dtype='period[M]', name='date', freq='M')

print (df.index.to_period('m').duplicated())
[False  True  True False  True False]

print (~df.index.to_period('m').duplicated())
[ True False False  True False  True]
```

Another solution is use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).head(1)
print (df1)
            A
date         
2020-01-02  4
2020-02-03  7
2020-03-02  1
```

Comment: If I get `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'`, what I do wrong?

Comment: @ker_laeda86 - There is no datetimeIndex, so need `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: @ker_laeda86 - If `date` is column use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and then `df[~df['date'].dt.to_period('m').duplicated()]`